# Rails - How to load vendor stylesheets and javascripts into application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, asset-pipeline

I have bootstrap and normalize css files under vendor like `vender/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css` `vender/assets/stylesheets/normalize.min.css`

How to load it into my application?

Comment: What's wrong with [official guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add in app/assets/stylesheets/application.css:

```
*= require bootstrap
*= require normalize
```

and reload the application.